# Conversion error in SQL where clause

Tags: php, sql, odbc

In a ODBC database table I have a column called pSDateTime that has a smalldatetime format.

I am running a search form on a PHP based website that has a dropdown where you can select 2015, 2014, 2013, etc.

I get this error when I submit the search:

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   '%2014%' to data type int., SQL state 22005 in SQLExecDirect

This is the query I run:

```
$query = "SELECT *
            FROM tbspeakers s join tbpresentations p on
            s.spkrId = p.spkrId

            join tbsessions ss on
            p.courseSessionid = ss.courseSessionId

            join tbcourses c on
            ss.courseId = c.courseId

            WHERE 
            (fname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR pTitle LIKE '%$searchq%' AND Year(pSDateTime) = '%$yearq%')

            ORDER BY pSDateTime DESC";
```

I have tried different types of conversion and keep getting the same error.  When I run the query on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it works fine.  I just can't seem to get the '%$yearq%' format/conversion to work out.

Comment: what happens if you switch the order '%$yearq%'= Year(pSDateTime)   I believe the engine will cast year to string instead of string to varchar.  Though I'm not sure access supports this type of transposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YEAR()` returns an integer.  That causes a problem for the equality, because the other argument is then converted.  And, that generates an error.

Two choices:

```
Year(pSDateTime) = $yearq
```

or:

```
datename(year, psDateTime) = '$yearq'
```

You probably don't want the wildcards `%` for the `=`.  These only work with `LIKE`.

You should also figure out how to parameterize the values going into your query.  This makes it safer (preventing SQL injection) and often faster (by eliminating the re-compile each time you execute the code).

Comment: This works, thank you!  Yes I run `$_POST['search'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);
   $_POST['year'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['year']);`